# Defining a function that gets the highest product pairs in a list

Tags: python, list, func

I'm trying to find write a function that gives the product of the highest pair of adjacent elements in a list. For my code,

```
gala = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    for i in range(len(inputArray)):
        if inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1] > inputArray[i+1] * inputArray[i+2]:
            return  inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1] 
    elif inputArray[i+1] * inputArray[i+2] > inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1] and inputArray[i+1] * inputArray[i+2] > inputArray[i+2] * inputArray[i+3]:
        return  inputArray[i+1] * inputArray[i+2]
    elif inputArray[i+2] * inputArray[i+3] > inputArray[i+1] * inputArray[i+2] and inputArray[i+2] * inputArray[i+3] > inputArray[i+3] * inputArray[i+4]:
         return  inputArray[i+2] * inputArray[i+3]
    else:
        return inputArray[i+3] * inputArray[i+4] 
return adjacentElementsProduct

adjacentElementsProduct(gala)
```

Here the output would be 20 (since 4 x 5 is the highest adjacent pairs). This function works for the given list even if I change the order of the numbers and their sign. However, if the length of the list is changed  then the code breaks. If the list was

```
gala = [1, -6]
```

or

```
gala = [2, 5, 7, -9, 10, 0, 11]
```

I wanted the function  first list's output to would be -6 and second would be 35. But my function breaks for such lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i did correctly understood your issue, i think your function can be reduced to:

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(elm):
   if len(elm) < 2:
       return None
   return max(k*v for k, v in zip(elm, elm[1:]))
```

So:

```
>>> adjacentElementsProduct([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
20
>>> adjacentElementsProduct([1, -6])
-6
>>> adjacentElementsProduct([2, 5, 7, -9, 10, 0, 11])
35
```

Answer (score 1):

A modification of @ChihebNexus's approach:

```
from operator import mul

def adjacentElementsProduct(elm):
   if len(elm) < 2:
       return None
   return max(map(mul, elm, elm[1:]))
```

An even shorter version:

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(elm):
   return max(map(mul, elm, elm[1:])) if len(elm) < 2 else None
```

And another one:

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import starmap

def adjacentElementsProduct(elm):
   if len(elm) < 2:
       return None
   return max(starmap(mul, zip(elm, elm[1:])))
```